# using double value in for loop with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have learned about the working of for loop and all. I decided to pass a double value inside  the for loop. The code looks like:

```
name = 'dfsdf'
for index,string in name:
    print index
```

When I run the code it give me error like

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

When I have added a single value it works just fine. Why does it throws an error when I used two names? Can double values be passed with for statement in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can double values be passed with for statement in python?

Yes, but the sequence you're iterating over must contain elements which themselves contain two elements apiece. For example, `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]`. Ordinary strings don't fit the bill, but the return value of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) does.

```
>>> name = 'dfsdf'
>>> for index,string in enumerate(name):
...     print index
...
0
1
2
3
4

>>> for a,b in [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]:
...     print a
...
1
3
5
```

Comment: `for index, string in [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]:` The `for` loop iterates over the list of tuples, and on each iteration a tuple is unpacked into `index` and `string`.